# PHP inheritance constructor function didn't work

Tags: php, oop

Please check my issue i make a script but `$contractempsal` variable didn't work. i want employee salary but i got error. please check.

Follow is my code:-

```
<?php
class baseemp {

protected $firstname;
protected $lastname;

public function getfullname() {

return $this->firstname .''. $this->lastname; 

}   

 public function __construct($first,$last) {

$this->firstname="$first";
$this->lastname="$last";
}   

}

 class fulltimeemp extends baseemp {

public $monthlysal;

 public function monthlysalary() {

$this->monthlysal/12;

}   
}

  class contractemp extends baseemp {


public $hourlyrate;
public $totalhours;

  public function monthlysalaryy() {


$this->hourlyrate * $this->totalhours;
  }
   public function __construct($hourrate,$totalhoursd){

$this->hourlyrate="$hourrate";
$this->totalhours="$totalhoursd";

}   
  }

   $fulltimeemployee = new fulltimeemp("kannu"," singh");
    $contractempsal = new contractemp("400","5");

   echo $fulltimeemployee->getfullname();

   echo $contractempsal->getfullname();

    ?>
```

So, this is my code. please check and tell me where i am wrong Thanks

Please check my issue i make a script but `$contractempsal` variable didn't work. i want employee salary but i got error. please check.

Comment: "i got error"  _What_ error?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: sorry i didn't get error it's show blank screen

Comment: i just want to get employee salary but it's show nothing :(

Comment: Check your error logs and/or enable error reporting.

Comment: what you think from my code is this proper ok??

Comment: I test your code and I got "kannu singh" as result. So maybe the issue is not in your code but around ?

Comment: yeah kannu singh show from first variable name $fulltimeemployee which is okay. but $contractempsal didn't show anything ??

Comment: Because you never set a name for `$contractempsal`.  You have created two completely independent object instances.  The second (`$contractempsal`) knows nothing about the first.

Comment: will you please overwrite that code on my code please thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are really trying to achieve here.  `$fulltimeemployee` and `$contractempsal` have nothing to do with each other.  What are you trying to represent by having to object/variables?  Are those two really for the same person?

Comment: yeah for that really i am also confused. why employee salary didn't get ?? :( @PatrickQ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to update __construct function of constractemp class for then call `parent::__construct` to set first and last name.

```
<?php
class baseemp {

    protected $firstname;
    protected $lastname;

    public function getfullname() {
        return $this->firstname .''. $this->lastname; 
    }   

    public function __construct($first,$last) {
        $this->firstname="$first";
        $this->lastname="$last";
    }   
}

class fulltimeemp extends baseemp {

    public $monthlysal;

    public function monthlysalary() {
        $this->monthlysal/12;
    }   
}

class contractemp extends baseemp {

    public $hourlyrate;
    public $totalhours;

    public function monthlysalary() {
        return $this->hourlyrate * $this->totalhours;
    }
    public function __construct($first,$last, $hourrate, $totalhoursd){
        parent::__construct($first,$last);
        $this->hourlyrate="$hourrate";
        $this->totalhours="$totalhoursd";
    }   
}

$fulltimeemployee = new fulltimeemp("kannu"," singh");
$contractempsal = new contractemp("kannu"," singh", "400","5");

echo $fulltimeemployee->getfullname(); // display kannu singh

echo $contractempsal->getfullname(); // display kannu singh

echo $contractempsal->monthlysalary(); // display 2000
```

Comment: sorry your code is not working it's shows blank again nothing show employee salary in result :(

Comment: I just update, please take a look. So now, both functions display ''kannu singh". Is it that you want ?

Comment: just check please wait

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 1 for contractemp::setEmployeeFullname(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\oops\index.php on line 240 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\oops\index.php on line 217

Notice: Undefined variable: employeeFullName in D:\xampp\htdocs\oops\index.php on line 218

Comment: will you please update your code all in my php code please so then i check it fully

Comment: Did you not forget to define `public $employeeFullname;` in your contractemp class ? I test this code in http://phptester.net/ and that work well. I did'nt make any modification in your baseemp and fulltimeemp class.

Comment: I edit my answer with all your code. You can copy/paste it in the phptester.net for make some tests :)

Comment: Thank you so much but i didn't get result of this ?? $contractempsal = new contractemp("400","5");

Comment: how i can get result of this

Comment: Just call `monthlysalaryy` function (it's like a getter). For example : `echo $contractempsal->monthlysalaryy()`

Comment: yes it's worked where i am wrong in my code please tell me thanks

Comment: I have a better idea ! Please take a look : it's better way to do I think :)